# Disk space showing more usage than what is actually used

Tags: partitioning, 22.04, disk-usage, disk

On one Hetzner server I can't figure out why my disk drive is taking more space than what is actually running on it. df -h results:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            13G  1.3M   13G   1% /run
/dev/md2        1.8T  1.4T  324G  81% /
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        989M  149M  790M  16% /boot
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/0
/dev/loop1      384K  384K     0 100% /snap/lz4/3
/dev/loop5      384K  384K     0 100% /snap/lz4/4
/dev/loop0       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2015
/dev/loop2      106M  106M     0 100% /snap/core/16091
/dev/loop4      106M  106M     0 100% /snap/core/16202
overlay         1.8T  1.4T  324G  81% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/85110815787f3675a6dbe33fbca9111acbb7974231f7127e9bca3714ddbd5a5e/merged
/dev/loop6       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2105
```

As you can see, it shows 1.4T used but every other tool I use for checking sizes of directories shows different results:

du -ah / | sort -rh | head -n 20

```
712G    /
369G    /root
331G    /home
325G    /home/main
```

ncdu:

```
    368.3 GiB [##########] /root                                                                                                                              
    330.5 GiB [########  ] /home
    7.0 GiB [          ] /var
    3.4 GiB [          ] /usr
    1.0 GiB [          ] /snap
  891.7 MiB [          ] /lib
  148.4 MiB [          ] /boot
   42.6 MiB [          ] /tmp
   14.1 MiB [          ] /bin
   13.4 MiB [          ] /sbin
   12.3 MiB [          ] /etc
    5.7 MiB [          ] /lib32
    1.3 MiB [          ] /run
   20.0 KiB [          ]  installimage.debug
   16.0 KiB [          ] /opt
e  16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
    8.0 KiB [          ] /media
    4.0 KiB [          ] /lib64
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /srv
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /mnt
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /celestia
    4.0 KiB [          ]  installimage.conf
.   0.0   B [          ] /proc
    0.0   B [          ] /sys
    0.0   B [          ] /dev
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz
```

Comment: Did you run `du -ah /` as root?

Comment: Yep, see below:

root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal:/# du -ah / | sort -rh | head -n 20

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* last year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Comment: It might help if you're specific with your details; including release (your last comment says it's 18.04! not 22.04), and what you're worried about... eg. The system I'm using now is installed on a 250GB SSD; of which 96GB is allocated to my `/`, however if I use `ncdu` and explore sizes it'll show 33TB of data on `/`, because I have a number of mounts on it; meaning data is available on directories of `/` that is stored elsewhere (*including network file-servers in my case*).   If I wanted to explore what I'd done, I'd starting looking at my *file-system table* or my mounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons space may be taken up by things other than visible files:

- A program has hidden temporary files open. On Linux, programs frequently create files then delete them immediately while keeping them open to ensure they are deleted at unmount. https://serverfault.com/questions/834912/no-space-on-ext4-partition-left-with-files-not-summing-up-to-used-space-and-with . They can be found looking in `/proc/*/fd/` or `sudo lsof | grep deleted`. Kill the process to free the space or reboot
- Files hidden by overmounts: https://superuser.com/questions/1409372/difference-in-free-disk-space-ncdu-and-df . Try `mount --bind / /mnt && du -ah /mnt`
- Reserved space for root: https://superuser.com/questions/1346350/is-there-a-way-to-make-ext-filesystems-use-less-space-for-themselves-in-linux . `sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/md2`
- Extra file metadata such as from `setcap`, SELinux, `fallocate`, `ftruncate` might not be recognized by the version of tools you are using
- A small amount of additional space is used for the superblock, backup superblocks, clusters, various space bitmaps, and the free inodes. This cannot be changed after filesystem creation, but next time an expert could choose to change the amount of inodes allocated
- Filesystem corruption. Run `fsck` from a LiveCD

Comment: Adding one more: on ZFS filesystems (which compress by default), `du` shows physical space consumed, vs `ls` or `stat` which show byte sizes. In text-rich directories this easily makes a 30-50% difference.

Comment: Your 1st recommendation was the issue here, and stopping that process solved it. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it solved me issue. Upvoted.